# Laravel Symbolic Link in Cpanel return 404 Not found

Tags: laravel, cpanel, symlink

i'm have Laravel application which i deployed in production server, i'm trying to create a symlink for my images that i can access it from public_html folder, the best solution i found to do it, is going to where my images are uploaded and do the following command

```
ln -sr storage ../public_html/storage
```

Now i can see a new folder created called storage ( refercing my images folder ) in public_html/storage, but when i try to access it from the browser it's returning 404 Not found, i tried everything but still not working

When i see error logs in Cpanel here's the error :

```
Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /home/c/public_html/storage/app/public/
```

Comment: your laravel project  outside of `public_html` expect `/public` folder? Need to know your directory structure

Comment: Yes, exactly, and i editing my index.php file to link autoload.php and app.php 
/../repositories/khidma/vendor/autoload.php
that's answering your question ?

Comment: If this happened for permission, then check your error logs from cPanel

Comment: i already checked permission, i don't think it's the reason, because everything works fine ! Expect getting images, it says 404 not found :(

Comment: add this to your .htaccess file https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202281/103342

Comment: @STA i have this in my .htaccess file but still not working
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
  Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymlinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    </IfModule>